KMP issue with add material3 dependency
Hello there i am starting my first project with kotlin multi platform
i am trying to add material3 dependency by adding this
implementation(libs.androidx.material3.android)

into
commonMain.dependencies {...}


unfortunately thats didn't work successfully with failure in those tasks

Task :composeApp:transformNativeMainCInteropDependenciesMetadataForIde FAILED
Task :composeApp:transformAppleMainCInteropDependenciesMetadataForIde FAILED
Task :composeApp:transformIosMainCInteropDependenciesMetadataForIde FAILED
Task :composeApp:transformNativeTestCInteropDependenciesMetadataForIde FAILED
Task :composeApp:transformAppleTestCInteropDependenciesMetadataForIde FAILED
Task :composeApp:transformIosTestCInteropDependenciesMetadataForIde FAILED

i have try to add this into
 androidMain.dependencies {..}

and done perfectly but i need to use it in common scoope
Looking forward to your answers thanks in advance.

run ./gradlew assembleDebug --info or --debug command from terminal to identify the root cause of this issue.

You can specify dependencies on KMP libraries only in commonMain.
If you'd like to develop KMP app with Material UI, then have a look on Compose Multiplatform by Jetbrains https://www.jetbrains.com/compose-multiplatform/
